# Kafka consumers not consuming after being idle for longtime

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Hi I have kafka consumers consuming data. The below command gives me consumer group command timeout.

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server b1:9092,b2:9092,b3:9092,b4:9092,b5:9092,b6:9092,b7:9092,b8:9092,b9:9092,b10:9092,b11:9092,b12:9092,b13:9092 --describe --group testgroup
```

**Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to The consumer group command timed out while waiting for group to initialize:**

All the consumers have been consuming the data for more than 26 hours. There was gap for more than 6hours as the producers stopped producing the data anymore for these 6hours.

I am suspecting there is some IDLE time which may have disconnected the connect between the consumer groups with the consumers. All the consumers are consuming with a poll interval of 100ms `poll(100)`.

This scenario has been observed for more than 3times. Any help from Kafka experts is appreciated. Thanks.

Code:

```java
@Service
public class DedupeConsumerService {

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DedupeConsumerService.class);

    @Autowired
    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Autowired
    private PropertyConfig config;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void consume() {

        String topic = config.getDedupServiceConsumerTopic();
        String consGroup = config.getDedupServiceConsGroup();

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
        props.put("session.timeout.ms", "20000");
        props.put("max.poll.records", "10000");

        KafkaConsumer<String, AvroSyslogMessage> consumer = new GenericConsumer<String, AvroSyslogMessage>().initialize(topic, consGroup, STREAMSERDE.STRINGDESER, STREAMSERDE.AVRODESER, props);

        logger.info("Dedupe Kafka Consumer Initialized......");

        try {
            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, AvroSyslogMessage> records = consumer.poll(100);
                if (records.count() > 0) {

                    }


                    logger.info("Number of Records:: " + records.count() + " Time took to process poll :: " + durationInMilliSec);

                }
            }

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            logger.error("Error occured while processing message", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            logger.debug("dedupe kafka consume is closing");
            consumer.close();
        }

    }

}
```

I tried making the poll time as `Integer.MAX_VALUE` this did not help.

Comment: which version kafka you are using ?

Comment: I am using kafka 2.12-0.11.0.0

Comment: Any errors in the consumer logs?

Comment: There was a rebalance which happened org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.

Comment: After this the cluster recovered and went on consuming more than 15Million data.

Answer (score 0):

Consider configuring the heartbeat setting for your consumers: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#consumerconfigs_heartbeat.interval.ms

Heartbeat will make sure the connection is not automatically shut down (much like keep-alive).